# How can I fix inconsistent display of UTF-8 data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18 and properly handle this data?

Tags: utf-8, sql-server-2019

I entered this query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 connected to a SQL Server 2019 database:

```
insert into URLs (URL, QuestionID) 
values ('⑨⑧⑦', 'sample')
```

The columns are both of `nvarchar` datatype.

When I run this query:

```
select * 
from URLs 
where URL = '⑨⑧⑦'
```

the inserted row is found, but the special characters are displayed in Management Studio as `???`.

There are other rows in the same table that were inserted programmatically with database components where a T-SQL query in SSMS displays the special characters in these same fields; however, SQL queries don't find these rows when the special characters are in a where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are "special" characters, and the column's datatype is `nvarchar` - then you **MUST** use a `N'...'` prefix for your string literals to avoid unwanted conversion back to non-Unicode values.

Use this

```
INSERT INTO URLs (URL, QuestionID) 
VALUES (N'⑨⑧⑦', N'sample')
```

and this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM URLs 
WHERE URL = N'⑨⑧⑦'
```

to ensure your characters are really treated **as Unicode** everywhere it's relevant.